# Is there a way to get Chrome to translate dynamic text added via Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, internationalization

A user visits my web page written in English and Chrome asks if a user in Spain would like to translate it to Spanish.

This works great. But then I have Javascript on the page that inserts text dynamically, which appears in English. Is there a way in Javascript or HTML I can get Chrome to translate the new text?

This is a web page and not a Chrome extension.

Comment: You can use the api of google transalate https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/libraries/v2/overview-v2